# Time Moves On Answers

Tags: discussion

There is a question on the legality of a Labour policy on charging VAT on school fees [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47869/is-vat-on-private-school-tuition-fees-against-eu-law/47875#47875);

I put a wait and see answer on it a couple of days ago as the manifesto had not yet been published.

As expected the 2019 Manifesto doesn't include any intention to charge VAT on school fees and I wondered how I should proceed at this point, and if there was some more general advice on moving target questions like this.

My first instinct would be to create a second answer with "As the manifesto is now out..." the weird thing is that it would mostly say "the suppositions in my previous answer are correct". Just with some quotes from the new manifesto.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you misunderstood this question. While the leaked draft of the Labour manifesto was the trigger for the question, the quesition itself is about whether or not this is possible to do according to EU rights. The legal situation does not change whether or not this proposal is actually seriously pursued or not.

But I am actually making the same mistake right now with this meta-question: Addressing the trigger of the question and not the question itself.

When an answer is no longer correct or appropriate, then you should update the answer by editing it.

Comment: Even if the answer has up/down votes? Or possibly selected as the Answer? (Not the case here, but it could be elsewhere). I guess scale of the edit is part of the answer to that.

Comment: @Jontia it depends, I think you need to use your own judgement mostly. If you are expanding on the previous position it's fine, others can see the edit log. If you're withdrawing the old answer by replacing it with a different opposing answer, that may be worse. In some cases, if it's not really opposing to the old answer, it may be done by editing making clear which parts are new and old. If it really goes against the old answer you can provide a new answer, that way voters can vote on one answer different from another. But again, it depends a lot on a case by case basis.